QTableWidget in custom ui form
I try to use QTableWidget in my ui attribute form created in Qt Designer to show attribute same way as if I used Drag and Drop Designer and Value Relation with multiple selection.

It used to work like that, but now the table is just empty.
I don't relaise, that I would make any change that could couse this issue. I use QGIS 3.38, but it didn't work in older version either.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question, and your post should contain some code.
